# globals declared by a web application in global scope

Tags: javascript, firefox, memory-leaks

Is there any way to find out all the variables declared/injected by a web application in global scope (window) ? I want to remove all those declared things from window on body unload so that when the tab gets closed, it releases memory taken by it.

Reason to do it: Firefox maintains global heap for all the tabs. Thus closing tab doesn't claim memory.

Answer (score 2):

> Reason to do it: Firefox maintains global heap for all the tabs. Thus closing tab doesn't claim memory.

Can you provide a citation for that? I'm sure Firefox does release the relevant memory at some point. It would become an unusable memory hog very quickly otherwise.

Answering the question you actually asked: You can build a list of the property names on `window` before loading the application:

```
var name;
var names = [];

for (name in window) {
    names.push(name);
}
```

...and then remove any that aren't on that list at the end:

```
for (name in window) {
    if (names.indexOf(name) === -1) {
        window[name] = undefined; // See below for why not `delete`
    }
}
```

Note that in most cases, you won't be able to actually remove the property (e.g., `delete window.foo;` mostly won't work), because A) If the property was created via `var`, you can't delete it, and B) Most versions of IE won't let you `delete` *any* property of `window`. But you could assign `undefined` to them.

Or rather than an array, it might be easier to check for property names later if you use an object:

```
var name;
var names = {};

for (name in window) {
    names[name] = 1;
}
```

Then the check becomes:

```
for (name in window) {
    if (!names.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        window[name] = undefined; // See above for why not `delete`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check out this thread for a number of different approaches:
[Detecting and reporting user defined global variables](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jsmentors/pocyKCgm7cU/discussion)

A notable trick worth mentioning is creating an iframe and comparing iframe's window object properties with your current window object properties. The advantage of this approach is that you can use it at any time, even after your application has launched, you can even run it periodically.